# jquery not working on page load

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, fullcalendar, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm currently working in asp.net mvc 4 and I'm trying to add the fullcalendar to my project. The fullcalendar is found here: http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/

When I click my actionlink, my calendar won't load. I can't seem to find why it doesn't work.

Here's the code:

CSHTML

```
@section JavaScript
{
    <link href="@Url.Content("/Content/fullcalendar.css") " rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.11.min.js")"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("/Scripts/fullcalendar.js")"></script>
    @*    <script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("/Scripts/fullcalendar.min.js")"></script>*@
}
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Tijdregistratie";
}
<script type='text/javascript'>
    $(document).ready(function () {

        var date = new Date();
        var d = date.getDate();
        var m = date.getMonth();
        var y = date.getFullYear();

        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            header: {
                left: 'prev',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'next'
            },
            editable: true,
            events: "/TijdRegistratie/GetGeplandeTaken/"
        });
    });
</script>
<div id='calendar'>
</div>
```

CONTROLLER

```
private TijdRegistratieService.ITijdRegistratieService _tijdRegistratieClient;

        public TijdRegistratieController()
        {
            _tijdRegistratieClient = new TijdRegistratieService.TijdRegistratieServiceClient();
        }

        public ActionResult TijdRegistratieOverzicht()
        {


            return View("TijdRegistratieOverzicht");
        }

        public JsonResult GetGeplandeTaken(double start, double end)
        {
            String beginDatum = ConvertFromUnixTimestamp(start).ToString();
            String eindDatum = ConvertFromUnixTimestamp(end).ToString();

            int psnID = (int)HttpContext.Session["userPSNID"];

            var geplandeTaken = _tijdRegistratieClient.GetGeregistreerdeTaken(1, beginDatum, eindDatum);

            var eventList = from e in geplandeTaken
                            select new
                            {
                                id = e.taakID,
                                title = e.BeginUur.Substring(0, e.BeginUur.Length - 3) + " - " + e.EindUur.Substring(0, e.EindUur.Length - 3),
                                start = string.Format("{0:u}", e.BeginDatum),
                                end = string.Format("{0:u}", e.EindDatum)
                                //allDay = false
                            };

            var rows = eventList.ToArray();

            return Json(rows, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }

        private static DateTime ConvertFromUnixTimestamp(double timestamp)
        {
            var origin = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);

            return origin.AddSeconds(timestamp);
        }
```

Layout.cshtml (automaticly loaded in every page)

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <link href="~/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
    <link href="@System.Web.Optimization.BundleTable.Bundles.ResolveBundleUrl("~/Content/css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/autocomplete.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
    <script src="@System.Web.Optimization.BundleTable.Bundles.ResolveBundleUrl("~/Scripts/js")"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0.1/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://dev.jtsage.com/cdn/datebox/latest/jquery.mobile.datebox.min.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://dev.jtsage.com/cdn/datebox/latest/jquery.mobile.datebox.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://dev.jtsage.com/cdn/datebox/i8n/jquery.mobile.datebox.i8n.en.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://dev.jtsage.com/cdn/datebox/latest/jquery.mobile.datebox.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://dev.jtsage.com/cdn/datebox/i8n/jquery.mobile.datebox.i8n.en.js"></script>

    @RenderSection("JavaScript", required: false)
    <script>
```

So I'm currently wondering on how I could fix this. This is my second project in which I'm using JQuery, so forgive me if I missed something obvious.

EDIT: When running in Firefox I get the following error in firebug: fullCalendar is not a function.

Comment: @EmRA228 posted a correct answer. Unfortunately it got downvoted incorrectly by Ohgodwhy. In the source code that the OP showed there's no reference to jQuery whatsoever. I am voting to undelete his answer and will upvote it as soon as it is undeleted. And now of course there are other answers that state exactly the same thing as the incorrectly IMHO deleted first answer which deserves the credit.

Comment: Seems like it doesn't work. My colleague (who worked on the project before I did) suddenly mentioned he loads everyting in a different page. The Jquery is loaded automaticly in every page because of this. I'll add the page to my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to remove:

```
@section JavaScript
{
    <link href="@Url.Content("/Content/fullcalendar.css") " rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.11.min.js")"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("/Scripts/fullcalendar.js")"></script>
    @*    <script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("/Scripts/fullcalendar.min.js")"></script>*@
}
```

from your cshtml page and added them to your main loading page. Now it would load on every page, and it would work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

=)))))

you did not include "jquery.js"

download newest version from http://jquery.com

Comment: If you had clicked the link, and saw the page, you would notice that the jQuery file is indeed being included. Downvote for trying to get instant karma.

Comment: Actually that's the JQuery-ui file. I forgot to add the jquery uploading page to my original post. I added it afterwards. This was a valid post when EmRa228 posted, so downvoting seems like a joke.

Answer (score 0):

You have forgotton to include the jQuery library, check the demo page you linked, it includes:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='/js/fullcalendar-1.5.3/jquery/jquery-1.7.1.min.js'></script>
```

Whereas your example does not.

Comment: Seems like it doesn't work. My colleague (who worked on the project before I did) suddenly mentioned he loads everyting in a different page. The Jquery is loaded automaticly in every page because of this. I'll add the page to my question.

Answer (score 0):

At first look, you don't need to pass 2 params to your method?

GetGeplandeTaken(**double start, double end**)

Your method is called from view? If you set a breakpoint on method , you have any values for that parameters?

Comment: Apparently the method gets the parameters automaticly from the jquery. Don't ask me why, but the parameters don't give errors. If I go to the page itself, everything else works fine. It's just the linking to the page with my actionlink that doesn't work. All my other actionlinks work fine, so I'm guessing it's a problem with the JQuery.

Comment: Can you add a button on your page and onclick event, put your current $(document).ready code? Just check if there are issues regarding document.ready.

Comment: I have tested the code with a button. The button works. Which I click it, my calendar doesn't get loaded. It seems to be a loading problem with the fullcalendar function itself.

Comment: There are some additional options for calendar events: events: {
        url: '/myfeed.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            custom_param1: 'something',
            custom_param2: 'somethingelse'
        },
        error: function() {
            alert('there was an error while fetching events!');
        },
        color: 'yellow',   // a non-ajax option
        textColor: 'black' // a non-ajax option
    }    Try to show an error message on "error" to check if error is catched by error function. If yes , probably you can find the error message to be more specific.

Comment: I can't get it to throw an error the way you thought it would. Even when leaving everything blank and just calling upon the function fullCalendar does nothing. The button works everytime though.